# Flutter FutureBuilder rebuilds unnecessarily when navigate between screens

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-futurebuilder

My FutureBuilder rebuilds unnecessarily when navigate between screens. Each time I have to get the download URL from the Firebase Storage and this results in extremely flickering. How can I prevent that the FutureBuilder rebuilds everytime I navigate between screens?

I already tried the following solutions:

https://medium.com/saugo360/flutter-my-futurebuilder-keeps-firing-6e774830bc2

[Flutter Switching to Tab Reloads Widgets and runs FutureBuilder](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51224420/flutter-switching-to-tab-reloads-widgets-and-runs-futurebuilder/51225879#51225879)

But without success. With both the FutureBuilder get always rebuild.

**This is my code (Attempt 1):**

```
class _GuestbookCardImageState extends State<GuestbookCardImage> {
  final AsyncMemoizer _memoizer = AsyncMemoizer();

  _getFeaturedImages() {
    return this._memoizer.runOnce(() async {
      return await MyStorage().getDownloadUrl(widget.guestbook.imagePath);
    });
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Card(
      semanticContainer: true,
      clipBehavior: Clip.antiAliasWithSaveLayer,
      shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
        borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10.0),
      ),
      elevation: 2,
      margin: EdgeInsets.all(5),
      child: FutureBuilder(
          future: _getFeaturedImages(),
          builder: (context, snapshot) {
            if (snapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.waiting) {
              return GuestbookPlaceholder();
            } else {
              if (snapshot.data != null) {
                return Hero(
                  tag: "to_single_guestbook_" + widget.guestbook.entryCode,
                  child: Container(
                    width: Get.width / 1.7,
                    height: Get.height / 3.5,
                    child: Image.network(
                      snapshot.data,
                      fit: BoxFit.cover,
                    ),
                  ),
                );
              } else {
                return Hero(
                    tag: "to_single_guestbook_" + widget.guestbook.entryCode,
                    child: GuestbookPlaceholder());
              }
            }
          }),
    );
  }
}
```

**Attempt 2**

```
class _GuestbookCardImageState extends State<GuestbookCardImage> {
  Future<String> _future;

  @override
  void initState() {
    _future = MyStorage().getDownloadUrl(widget.guestbook.imagePath);
    super.initState();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Card(
      semanticContainer: true,
      clipBehavior: Clip.antiAliasWithSaveLayer,
      shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
        borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10.0),
      ),
      elevation: 2,
      margin: EdgeInsets.all(5),
      child: FutureBuilder(
          future: _future,
          builder: (context, snapshot) {
            if (snapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.waiting) {
              return GuestbookPlaceholder();
            } else {
              if (snapshot.data != null) {
                return Hero(
                  tag: "to_single_guestbook_" + widget.guestbook.entryCode,
                  child: Container(
                    width: Get.width / 1.7,
                    height: Get.height / 3.5,
                    child: CachedNetworkImage(
                        imageUrl: snapshot.data, fit: BoxFit.cover),
                  ),
                );
              } else {
                return Hero(
                    tag: "to_single_guestbook_" + widget.guestbook.entryCode,
                    child: GuestbookPlaceholder());
              }
            }
          }),
    );
  }
}
```

**What I expect**

I expect that after changing the screen and return to the initial screen my images still appearing without the need of reload. I am using Hero animation for the images. This loading behavior destroys my animation because while loading the image urls it shows a placeholder.

**A small video how this looks: (And this happens also if I push to the detail screen and pop back to the initial screen)**

[image]

What could I do to solve this issue?

Comment: Please share your attempts. It doesn't appear that you have tried the answers of the linked questions.

Comment: I´ve edited my code with both attempts. Thank you :)

Comment: Please shared the behavior for both and how it's undesirable. There is **no way to stop builds**.  They're necessary for flutter to function properly.

Comment: I´ve edited my question again with the additional information which behavior I expect.

Comment: Where is your attempt with `AutomaticKeepAliveClientMixin`? You need to share more code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you need to go higher in the widget tree and preserve the state of your page. you can try [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62980447/automatickeepaliveclientmixin-not-working-with-a-bottomnavigationbar-page/62980902#62980902) solution. The solution is to use `PageView` widget to display your screen through the navigation bar, and the `PageView` allowing you to save the page state easily.

Comment: But the Futurebuilder also rebuilds if I push to another page and go back to the initial. It is not only the bottom navigation..

Comment: your page state should be preserved because of the 'PageView'. You assign a page controller to the pageview widget and set the 'keep page' argument to true inside the page controller instance. I think this is the best approach , try this solution

Comment: Just an additional question... what if for example I change some values on the object for which I am using the FutureBuilder? Then I want manually trigger a rebuild.... with the pageView solution I have forever the initial state. Is there a workaround for this? Thank you very much in advance!

Comment: you can setState the future itself

Comment: Thanks, but how can I add a condition? By default I don’t want that the future builder rebuilds, but only if there is an update in the database... so if the value changes... is there a best way to to this?

Comment: you need in some way to listen to changes in the db, and setState the future every time there is a change. one easy solution is to use stream or behavior subject. assign a stream controller in your db file. every time there is a change in the db, add new event to the stream (it can be even 'null'). where you want to listen and rebuild, just listen to the db stream and setState when an event occurs

Answer (score 0):

What helped me was setting the `memCacheWidth` property to be `screen width x devicePixelRatio`, so the image is cached in the highest resolution that will ever be necessary.

Note: if you want to do zooming, consider doing `width x 10` (or some other number which works for your case).

```
CachedNetworkImage(
      imageUrl: url,
      memCacheWidth: mediaQuery.size.width.ceil() * mediaQuery.devicePixelRatio.ceil(),
      // ... other properties ...
),
```